# Can't import bookmarks from my user favorites folder into firefox

Tags: windows-10, firefox, bookmarks

I recently had a disk crash. have a backup. went out and bought a new computer with W10 on it. my favorites are in a folder (favorites) on the backup so I restored them and tried to import them into firefox. However the firefox import function only allows the import of HTML pages and not entire Windows folder structure containing the HTMLs. I can't Imagine I have to import one URL at a time. I don't have a working Windows 7 system including Explorer 11 from which to import the favorites so how do I do it or am I out of luck??

Comment: Firefox doesn't use Favorites folder. Are you sure you aren't trying to pull IE favorites in Firefox ? Firefox bookmarks are stored in **%appdata%\mozilla\firefox\profiles** folder

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the .URLs files to a bookmark html file. Use these steps:

Copy the contents of your Favorites folder (from backup) to:

```
C:\Users\%username%\Favorites
```

Press WinKey + R, type `iexplore.exe` and press ENTER. This starts Internet Explorer.

Verify if favorites are shown under the Favorites menu in Internet Explorer. If you've copied them to the correct folder, then they should be displayed.

From the File menu, click `Import and Export`. Follow the on-screen instructions and create a bookmark.html file.

Import this file into Firefox using Firefox Bookmarks manager.